# Conjugating elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are the elements $(12)$ and $(23)$ conjugate elements in $S_3$? I am struggling to directly show that this is true. I know that they are, but when I calculate it I do not get the right answer.

If I set $x=(12)$ and $g=(23)$, I then want to show that $xg=gx$. So $$xg=(12)(23)$$ Would send $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $1$ ( since $3$ goes to $2$ and $2$ goes to $1$) and then $1$ to $2$).

Then form $$gx=(23)(12)$$ we get that $2$ goes to $1$, $3$ goes to $2$, and then $1$ goes to $3$.

But then $xg$ doesn't equal $gx$. Could some one please explain where I went wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check your definition of conjugate elements. Two elements $g$ and $x$ are conjugate if there is some element $h$ such that $g = hxh^{-1}$. It will not generally be true that $gx = xg$. (The latter occurs iff $g$ and $x$ **commute**.)

To show that $g$ and $x$ are conjugate, note that two elements of $S_3$ (or more generally, $S_n$ for any $n$) are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure, which is certainly the case of your $x = (12)$ and $g = (23)$: they are both $2$-cycles, aka transpositions.

To find an $h$ that gives $g = hxh^{-1}$, note that in order to "morph" $x=(12)$ into $g=(23)$, we need to change $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $3$, which is achieved by $h = (1 2 3)$. Check:
$$hxh^{-1} = (1 2 3) (12)(1 3 2) = (23) = g$$
So $g$ and $x$ are indeed conjugate.